# Was the Brahmaputra River created by Lord Brahma?

Tags: shiva, puranas, brahma

I want to know that was the river Brahmaputra created by Lord Brahma or any other God?

Comment: See [this](http://www.indianscriptures.com/sacred-places/rivers/brahmaputra) page.

Answer (score 4):

[Chapter 81](https://archive.org/details/KalikaPuranamVol.2AcharyaMrityunjayaTripathi/mode/1up) (*Kāmarūpamāhātmyavarṇana*) of *Kālikāpurāṇa* ([English Translation Link](https://archive.org/details/QCML_the-kalika-puran-translated-in-english-by-b-n-shastri-edited-by-surendra-pratap-nag-publishers-/page/n45/mode/2up)) describes the origin of the river *Brahmaputra* in the following way.

*I'm providing the Summarized English Translation of the translated Hindi text*

> Forermerly in the vicinity of the *Nilāchala* hills were situated many
> *kuṇḍa*s, like the *Apunarbhavakuṇḍa* (named such because the person who bathed here would never be reborn again), bathing in which people
> were obtaining permanent residence in *svarga*  directly after death
> by the grace of it's presiding deity, *Bhagavatī Kāmākhyā*. *Indra*
> complained to *Prajapati Brahmā* that *svarga* was getting overpopulated with
> people bathing in those *kuṇḍa*s & Yama complained that sinners were
> evading justice by bathing there. So Brahmā made humanity forget about
> the *tīrtha-māhātmya* of the *Yonipīṭha* & proceeded there to conceal
> the sacred *kuṇḍa*s of the site.
>
> On the way, he was hit by the arrows of *Kāmadeva* on seeing a
> *ṛṣipatnī* named *Amoghā* & deposited his seed on that spot. That seed was implanted in *Amoghā*'s womb by her husband, a sage named *Śāntanu*,
> which led to the birth of *Lauhitya*. *Lauhitya*'s physical appearance was
> that of a boy of crimson-red complexion wearing blue-garmets &
> gem-studded garland, holding a book & a lotus in his right arms, a
> spear & flag in his left arms, seeated on a dolphin & surrounded by a
> mass of clear water, so *Śāntanu* had him placed inside a artificially
> constructed *kuṇḍa* (identified as Paraśurāmakuṇḍa of south-eastern
> Aruṇācala Pradeśa from where the river Lohita originates) in the
> mountains. This *Lauhitya-kuṇḍa* was visited by *Paraśurāma* on his
> quest to relieve himself from the sin of matricide, incurred when his father, the sage *Jamadagni* ordered him to kill his mother *Reṇukā* for masturbating at the site of a copulating *Gandharva* couple. *Paraśurāma*, on
> being relieved from matricide after bathing in it, decided to make the waters of
> *Lauhitya-kuṇḍa* available to the massess. So he carved out a channel out of the *Lauhitya-kuṇḍa* into the sea which inadvertedly passed through *Kāmarūpa-kṣetra* & submerged the *kuṇḍa*s of *Yonipiṭha* within its waters. The channel dug by *Paraśurāma* became the river *Lauhitya* aka
> *Brahmaputra*.

On a sidenote, a [legend](https://en.banglapedia.org/index.php?title=Langalband) is prevalent among Hindus of eastern Bengal that while approaching near the sea, *Lauhitya* was distracted by the beauty of a local rivulet named *Śitalakhyā* & deviated from the channel carved by *Paraśurāma* to merge with her, which caused *Paraśurāma* to stop dragging his plough (with which he had been carving out *Brahmaputra*'s channel till then) & cursed *Lauhitya* to lose his sin-relieving properties. However on *Lauhitya*'s request, he decreed that *Lauhitya* would possess his sin-relieving powers only on the 8th day of the bright fortnight in the month of *Caitra*. On that day, Hindus of eastern Bengal gather in large numbers at the banks of the old riverbed of Brahmaputra at *Laṅgalabandha* (where *Paraśurāma* is believed to have  pronounced the curse on *Lauhitya*), situated in Nārāyaṇagañja district of present day Bāṇglādeśa to take bath in the river uttering the following *pranāma-mantra*

> ब्रह्मपुत्र महाभाग शान्तनोः कुलनन्दन । अमोघागर्भसम्भूत पापं लौहित्य मे हर ।। त्वं ब्रह्मपुत्र भुवनतारण तीर्थराज गम्भीरनीर परिपूरित सर्वदेह । त्वद्दर्शन हरतु मे भवघोरदुःखं संयोगतः कलियुगे भगवन्नमस्ते ।।

Answer (score 1):

No, the Brahmaputra river was not created by Brahma.

It was actually created by Parashuram.

Parashuram, after beheading his mother, found his axe sticking to his palm because he had committed a sin.

To relive the sin, he went to several places, but without any success.

Finally, he went to Manasarovar, where he could relieve himself of the sin.

He then decided to make way for the water in the sarovar to go to various places on the earth as a river. The river is Brahmaputra.

Comment: you should cite sources!